# Can't use Localizable.strings inside Info.plist

Tags: ios, localization, info.plist

In an iOS app I need to include the following inside the `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>"This app needs microphone access for voice recording."</string>
```

All works as fas as functionality is concerned. The user is able to access the microphone after authorization.

Here is what worries me:

I want to localise the string. And for some reason I cannot make it work.

I tried various ways of putting something like:

```
"MICUSE" = "This app needs microphone access for voice recording.";
```

in one `InfoPlist.strings` file and:

```
"MICUSE" = "This app needs microphone access for voice recording.(auf Deutsch)";
```

in another `InfoPlist.strings`.

And then change my `Info.plist` file to:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>${MICUSE}</string>
```

or:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(MICUSE)</string>
```

Also being careful about including the files in the right target.
But nothing works.

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 1):

You should use InfoPlist.strings file to localize values of Info.plist. To do this, go to File->New->File, choose Strings File under Resource tab of iOS, name it InfoPlist, and create. Open and insert the Info.plist values you want to localize like:

"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "Description of this";
Now you can localize InfoPlist.strings file with translations. Good Luck!

EDIT:

select the localization options, or enable localization if needed,

right side editor

you should be able to see the file also on the left side editor.

Comment: Fine, but this is what I am already doing. Isn't it? By the way which syntax do you use inside Info.plist?